# What is the best way to delete duplicate records from a database table?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table in the database that does not contain any key, now I want to delete that row from the table which is totally duplicate.

So what is the best way to eliminate duplicate records?

1. User `ROW_NUMBER()` function with `PARTITION BY`.
2. Use a `TEMP` table - `CREATE` new `TEMP` table with proper `unique index`. Copy distinct rows into it. `TRUNCATE` old table and re-insert the data and drop `TEMP` table.
3. Use `Recursive CTE`.

any other best option,then please mention. Looking forward to response.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, mysql, postgresql...?

Comment: This is a general question for any database, if it depends on the database then please describe for Postgresql and MySQL.

Comment: *what is the best way to eliminate duplicate records?* Create new table with proper unique index. Copy distinct rows into it. Drop old table and rename new.

Comment: For larger data sets, it can be quicker to create a new table, retaining only the rows you want to keep. Then drop the old table. Then rename, and properly index, the new table.

Comment: you guys mean to say the second option.

Answer (score 0):

You also used query like this according to your requirement.

```
pool.query("DELETE FROM public.table1 x USING public.table1 y WHERE x.id < y.id AND x.column_name = y.column_name", (err,result) => {
    if(err) { console.log("Recode not delete...."+err); }
    if(result){ console.log('Duplicate recode deleted..'); }
}); /* old all same recode deleted */
```

According to requirement change where conditions.